# Debug Error: ClosedConnectionException in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, xdebug, jvm-arguments

I need to debug a package. When I try debugging it gives the following error:

```
  Failed to connect to remote VM com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.ClosedConnectionException
```

Debug configurations:

```
Connection type: Standard(Socket Attach)
Host: localhost
Port: 8000
Allow Termination of remote VM checkbox checked.
```

I have the server running on my desktop, on port 8000. Terminal output:

```
INFO:  6361@<desktop name> listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000
INFO:  6361@<desktop name> listening on https://0.0.0.0:8001
```

I tried adding debug jvmargs in build.xml:

```
<target name="server" depends="build">          

               <jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000" />

   </target>
```

But bb server failes giving error:

```
 Problem: failed to create task or type jvmarg
 Cause: The name is undefined.
```

I am testing the package using RestClient, and its working fine, But not able to debug.

Any leads appreciated